# Tag rename request: jenkins-workflow → jenkins-pipeline

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

The [jenkins-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-workflow) tag was created to manage questions about a Jenkins (continuous integration tool) plugin suite hosted [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/), and originally named “Workflow”. Recently it was resolved by the creator of Jenkins and the maintainers of the feature to rename it to “Pipeline” to better reflect what prospective users would be looking for. (For compatibility reasons, the term *workflow* continues to be used in internal code names.) [JENKINS-31153](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31153) is the tracking issue in JIRA. The rename is in effect as of the recent [1.13 release](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/d353e6fb055a5e2aebfebac21abecf14babb0fb6/CHANGES.md#113-jan-18-2016) of the plugins.

As per [these instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197731/181977), this is a request to moderators for the tag to be renamed [jenkins-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline), with existing questions (161 as of this writing) switched accordingly. [jenkins-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-workflow) could be retained as a tag synonym.

As the creator of the tag I have already submitted an edit for its summary and description.

Comment: [As of a month ago](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13297954) the [tag:jenkins-workflow] excerpt is now advertising [tag:jenkins-pipeline] as an alternative, which is sort of unfortunate since the questions are now split between them. Can we simply do a bulk tag-rename?

Comment: The questions were split between the two tags already before I updated the [jenkins-workflow tag excerpt](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29412427/revisions) to use [jenkins-pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline) instead.

Comment: What I find also bad is that [tag:jenkins-pipeline] is [is suggested to be come a synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jenkins-workflow/synonyms) for [tag:jenkins-workflow]. Instead, it should be the other way around (so we would have to vote that suggestion to a -2 to get it deleted. Then [tag:jenkins-pipeline] could be suggested as master and the others as synonym.

Comment: Given the explanations, the renaming probably cannot be done, as the target tag already exists.. Is synonym the way to go?

Comment: I read [What are tag synonyms and merged tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) again. I think we just need to suggest [tag:jenkins-workflow] as synonym for [tag:jenkins-pipeline] on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jenkins-pipeline/synonyms) page (and vote for it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As renaming a tag [requires](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197731/181977) the target tag to *not* exist, the original plan would probably not work out anymore.

Therefore, I suggest the following procedure:

1. **✓** Reject the current suggestion to make [jenkins-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline) a synonym for [jenkins-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-workflow) here: [jenkins-workflow/synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jenkins-workflow/synonyms) (requires **-2** voting to be deleted). If this would be accepted, the [jenkins-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline) would always be converted to [jenkins-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-workflow).
2. **✓** Suggest [jenkins-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-workflow) as a synonym for [jenkins-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline) here: [jenkins-pipeline/synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jenkins-pipeline/synonyms)
3. **TODO**: Upvote the proposal here: [jenkins-pipeline/synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jenkins-pipeline/synonyms) (requires **+4** voting to be accepted).

This gives us the benefits of [jenkins-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline) being the master and [jenkins-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-workflow) a synonym, which are according to [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work):

> All uses of the synonym tag for any given master tag are automatically converted to the master tag. So, users can enter a synonym tag when writing a question, but the master tag will be displayed when the question is loaded. Editing a question tagged with a synonym tag causes it to be replaced by the master tag. Similarly, when users search for questions tagged with a synonym, a list of questions tagged with the master will be displayed.
>   [..]
>
> When a synonym is created, the synonymous tag is not removed from questions, but cannot be added to new questions anymore (the master tag will be chosen instead)

The old questions could just keep the [jenkins-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-workflow), but no questions would automatically be tagged with [jenkins-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline).

Comment: Seems that it is more complicated. I downvoted [tag:jenkins-pipeline] as a synonym for [tag:jenkins-workflow]. I cannot downvote [tag:jenkinsfile] since apparently I created i. I cannot suggest [tag:jenkins-workflow] as a synonym for [tag:jenkins-pipeline] because the reverse synonym is already proposed. So I guess I need some assistance here.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to this, @JesseGlick. Could you approach one of the [top users of jenkins-workflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jenkins-workflow/topusers) to help down-vote this proposal? I assume you know some of them? I'm unfortunately not so well integrated into the Jenkins community, yet.

Comment: As said, once we have the -2, the proposal gets deleted and we should be able to suggest the reverse synonym.

Comment: [tag:jenkinsfile] is gone but [tag:jenkins-pipeline] remains.

Comment: And I am unable to suggest [tag:jenkinsfile] as a synonym for [tag:jenkins-pipeline], due to some error about “chains”. How do we get the attention of moderators on this site?!

Comment: We're on track. Please now up-vote the new, correct synonym suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jenkins-pipeline/synonyms

Comment: Upvoted those two.